# Сайт на битриксе не сразу обновляет цены

Tags: php, битрикс, кэширование

Сайт на битрксе.
При обновлении цены через админку или через обмен с 1с цена у обычного пользователя обновляется не сразу. даже ctrl+f5 не сразу помогает.
Под админом цена меняется сразу после обновления страницы.

Comment: похоже на кеш bitrix, того компонента где смотрит пользователь на сайте (если в админке цены обновляются сразу). Что бы проверить можно, сбросить кеш bitrix (Настройки>Настройки продукта>Автокеширование). ctrl+f5 - это сброс кеша браузера, т.е. если bitrix закешил вывод компонента то это всегда и будет приходить в браузер. Тут нужно знать о каких компонентах речь/где смотрит цены обычный пользователь (кастомный/или нет) смотреть в сторону настроек кеша, может CACHE_TYPE = A поставить. Или читать в сторону тегированного кеша. У админа может быть, в панели управления стаять галочка без кеша.

Comment: Используется комплексный компонент каталога. CACHE_TYPE выставлял A и N - эффекта не дало. Единственное в списке товаров цена обновляется почти сразу, а в самой карточке со временем

Comment: нужно пройти по файлам вашего шаблона, комплексного компонента и посмотреть что бы параметр кеша CACHE_TYPE прокидывался в вызовы компонентов из этих файлов (в вашем случае нужен файл детального просмотра товара, detail.php или типа того). Наверно где то вручную забито 'Y'. Либо идти в шаблон компонента детального просмотра товара и смотреть откуда туда берутся данные, может быть в result_modifier метод который кешируется (это если кастомили всё).      Попробуйте просто сбросить кеш bitrix (Настройки>Настройки продукта>Автокеширование), скорее всего кеш битрикса какого то компонента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в технологии "Композитный сайт" в настройке режим перезаписи кеша.

В Стандартном режиме с задержкой перезаписи - кеш обновлялся только спустя две минуты, от сюда и задержка при изменений цены на сайте
[image: Режим перезаписи кеша]